# How to add each row in one column just like excel in Power BI?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

For instance: I have value 5 in cell A1 and when I do =5+A1 in excel it will do the job for the rest of the columns. How can I do exactly same in PowerBI? could anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to Table mode and click New Column.

[image]

```
Type MyColumn = Rates[size] + 5
```

Where [size] is base column as input (like A in excel) and MyColumn is the name of your new column.